# Privilege and badge links are displayed on stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange-button

When I click in [stackexchange-button](/questions/tagged/stackexchange-button) in http://stackexchange.com is displayed Privilege and Badge links form stackoverflow.com:

> [image: StackExchange Menu]

When I click in privileges link:

> [image: privileges]

When I click in Badge link:

> [image: badge]

[stackexchange-button](/questions/tagged/stackexchange-button) in meta.stackexchange:

> [image: meta]

Comment: No repro https://i.gyazo.com/c048111d3709943840f45681e30fac61.png, is it just me...?

Comment: Yup, Nick fixed it already. /cc @54D

Comment: @ShadowWizard Nice!